# Как не выводить значения 0 из sql таблицы? (Pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3

Всем привет. Впервые начал изучать SQLite и создаю тг-бота с БД (библиотека pytelegrambotapi). Таблицу писал вручную (помог человек). Всё сделано на мобилке. Но проблема в том, что бот выводит значения с 0, которые пользователю абсолютно не нужны. Например, в столбце tree2 много 0. Да, у меня код вообще неудобный и всё такое, но я, пока что, учусь. Пытался сделать через if-else, но ничего не изменилось. Искал примеры в интернете, подставлял, тоже не получалось. Буду рад, если мне укажут мои ошибки! Заранее спасибо.

Вот кусочек кода:

```
def func(message):
    furniture_name = message.text
    with con:
        data = con.execute("SELECT name FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data2 = con.execute("SELECT ctree FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data3 = con.execute("SELECT tree FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data4 = con.execute("SELECT ctree2 FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data5 = con.execute("SELECT tree2 FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data6 = con.execute("SELECT crude FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data7 = con.execute("SELECT rude FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data8 = con.execute("SELECT crude2 FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        data9 = con.execute("SELECT rude2 FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
        imya = data.fetchone() 
        countct = data2.fetchone()    
        countt = data3.fetchone()
        countct2 = data4.fetchone()
        countt2=data5.fetchone()
        countcr=data6.fetchone()
        countr=data7.fetchone()
        countcr2=data8.fetchone()
        countr2=data9.fetchone()
        
        
        
        if not imya:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❗Прости, я не могу найти такой декор(( Возможно, ты сделал ошибку ❗')
        else:
            countr2em = countr2[0]
            countcr2em = countcr2[0]
            countrem = countr[0]
            countcrem = countcr[0]
            countt2em = countt2[0]
            countct2em = countct2[0]
            counttem = countt[0]
            countctem = countct[0]
            imyaem = imya[0]
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Название мебели: " + "'" + str(imyaem) + "'\n\nДля этой мебели тебе потребуется: \n<b>" + str(countctem) + " " + str(counttem) + "\n" + str(countct2em) + " " + str(countt2em) + "\n" + str(countcrem) + " " + str(countrem) + "\n" + str(countcr2em) + " " + str(countr2em) +  "</b>\n", parse_mode='html')
            
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Приветик! Введи название мебели")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, func)
```

Пока что, бот выводит информацию вот так:

> Пользователь: Диван
>
> Бот: Название мебели: 'Диван'
>
> Для этой мебели тебе потребуется:
> 4 Берёзы
> 0
> 0 Железа
> 0 Досок

Нулей быть не должно.

Я пытаюсь сделать в таком виде:

> Пользователь: Диван
>
> Бот: Название мебели: 'Диван'
>
> Для этой мебели тебе потребуется:
> 4 Берёзы

Изменено:

````
    with con:
        furniture_name=message.text
        con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        row = con.execute("SELECT * FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name]).fetchone()
       
        if not row:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❗Прости, я не могу найти такой декор(( Возможно, ты сделал ошибку ❗')
            return

        name = row['name']
        ctree = row['ctree']
        tree = row['tree']
        ctree2 = row['ctree2']
        tree2 = row['tree2']
        crude = row['crude']
        rude = row['rude']
        crude2 = row['crude2']
        rude2 = row['rude2']
        
        lines = [
            f'Название мебели: {name}',
            ' ',
            'Для этой мебели тебе потребуется:',
        ]
        if ctree:
            lines.append(f'ctree: {ctree}')
        if tree:
            lines.append(f'tree: {tree}')
        if ctree2:
            lines.append(f'ctree2: {ctree2}')
        if tree2:
            lines.append(f'tree2: {tree2}')
        
        
   

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(lines)+ str(ctree) + str(tree) + str(ctree2) + str(tree2), parse_mode='html')```
````

Comment: 1) Я бы одним запросом вытащил все поля 2) Для удобства можно их не указывать явно, а использовать `*` и [результат вернуть как словарь](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8e61ed77c4b773c3add1d22ad87b7c1d06026838/sqlite3__examples/select_as_dict.py#L27) 3) При заполнении текста по результатам не добавлять те, которые `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замечания:

- Используйте один запрос, вернув нужные поля
- Для удобства можно использовать `con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`, чтобы результатом был объект подобный словарю, тогда можно будет по названиям полей, а не их индексам, запрашивать значения

  - Вместо можно и без этого, но нужно будет перечислить вместо `*` все поля, а после сделать распаковку по переменным, мини пример:

    ```
    row = con.execute("SELECT name, ctree, tree FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name]).fetchone()
    ...
    name, ctree, tree = row
    ```
- Вместо конкатенации строки может быть проще подготовить список строк, который будет объединен в текст:

Пример:

```
import sqlite3
...

with con:
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    row = con.execute("SELECT * FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name]).fetchone()
    if not row:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❗Прости, я не могу найти такой декор(( Возможно, ты сделал ошибку ❗')
        return

    name = row['name']
    ctree = row['ctree']
    tree = row['tree']
    ctree2 = row['ctree2']
    tree2 = row['tree2']
    crude = row['crude']
    rude = row['rude']
    crude2 = row['crude2']
    rude2 = row['rude2']
    
    lines = [
        f'Название мебели: {name}',
        '',
        'Для этой мебели тебе потребуется:',
    ]
    if ctree:
        lines.append(f'ctree: {ctree}')
    if tree:
        lines.append(f'tree: {tree}')
    
    И так перечислить все поля...

    text = '\n'.join(lines)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, parse_mode='html')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Учту ваши замечания. Как я могу тогда убрать квадратные скобки с запятой? В своём коде создавал новую 'переменную', присваивал те значения и приписывал [0]. Точно так же, верно?

Comment: В моем коде не нужно обращаться по индексу. Метод `fetchone` вернет или `None` (значений нет), или контейнер с данными (по-моему, там кортеж), а т.к. вы в переменные присваивали результат `fetchone`, то понадобилось после вызывать `[0]`, чтобы значения получить

Comment: Тогда, как можно убрать в Вашем коде квадратные скобки при выводе?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. У меня не должно выводиться с квадратными скобками в сообщении. Покажите ваш текущий с проблемой, например добавьте его в вопрос ниже старого или залейте куда-либо, типа pastebin или github gist и ссылкой

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Внизу Ваш код, единственное, что я изменил это вместо ```text``` в ```bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)``` вставил конкатенацию   для вывода.  
   Бот выводит в таком виде:

Comment: ['Название мебели: Изношенный меч', ' ', 'Для этой мебели тебе потребуется:', 'ctree: 4', 'tree: Пихты']4Пихты0

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн, блин, у меня строка потерялась: `text = '\n'.join(lines)`. Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё отлично заработало!

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно что-то типа:

```
"SELECT rude2 FROM furniture WHERE rude2 is not null"
или
"SELECT rude2 FROM furniture WHERE rude2 <> '0'"
```

Дословно: Выбрать руду из таблицы где руда не ровна null - пустому значению, не равна нулю - '0' - символ. (0 - число), и это с учетом если я правильно понял.

Первая ссылка в гугл:

```
with con:    
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("SELECT name, ctree, tree, ctree2 и т.д. FROM furniture WHERE name <> 0 and ctree <> 0 and tree <> 0 и тд.")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
 
    for row in rows:
        print row
```

---

```
name = message.text
f"SELECT rude2 FROM furniture WHERE name = {name} and rude2 <> '0' and ..."
или
"SELECT rude2 FROM furniture WHERE name = " + name + " and rude2 <> '0' and ..."
```

Имя можно передавать примерно так.

Comment: Да, но тогда он выводит ошибку ```File "<string>", line 45, in func
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```   Я изменил строку в таком виде: ```data4 = con.execute("SELECT ctree2 FROM furniture WHERE name=? AND ctree2<>0", [furniture_name])```  name=? - должно быть обязательно, так как бот должен вывести информацию про мебель, которую просит пользователь

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн потому что вы обращаетесь к пустому значению. Вот тут и должна быть логика программы. Вы не достали из базы эти значения потому что они равны 0. Но все же помещаете их в переменные

Comment: что лично приходит в голову? Помещать данные из бд в списки или им подобные конструкции. Вы не можете наверняка знать будет ли расширяться у вас БД или нет

Comment: Простите, но мне сложно понять о чём Вы говорите. Что значит не достал значения из БД? Объясните подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн исправил ответ, я бы начал с этого

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн, объясняю - у вас есть таблица со столбцами - name ctree и тд. Вы используйте запрос с условием where <> 0 - тем самым по логике если например crtee == 0 то с базы оно браться не будет, но тк вы используйте для каждого столбца отдельную переменную и пытаетесь взять ВСЕ из БД - то в последствии изза условия ваша переменная будет пустая, и выводить ошибку

Comment: Вам нужно одним запросом с условием брать с бд то что вам нужно upd: не нужно, а я бы советовал, скажу так.

Comment: Ааааааа, понял, спасибо за объяснение)) Сейчас попробую

Comment: @СёгунРайдэн дополнил пример запроса. Как то так.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato, так не нужно делать `f"SELECT rude2 FROM furniture WHERE name = {name} and rude2 <> '0' and ..."`, используйте binding-параметры как это было у автора вопроса

Comment: @gil9red, + бахнул вам (: спасибо, за уточнение. добавил бы - что в sql так называемые binding - параметры позволяют избегать sql инъекций если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato, спасибо, да верно, так можно избежать sql-инъекции :)

Answer (score -1):

я абсолютно не понимаю в питоне, но вот набросал способ, который возможно тебе поможет.

```
text = ''
a = 3
b = 0
if a > 0:
    text += 'Железа: '+str(a)
if b > 0:
    text += 'Березы: '+str(b)
print(text)
```

Выводит: "Железа: 3", а если березы будет больше чем 0 то и ее покажет. Дальше уже сам под себя подстрой.

Comment: Думаю, что Вы бы очень сдружились с питоном)) но, к сожалению, метод if, как я говорил раньше, не работает(((